# "Select" clause in HQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

i´m trying different types of query but when i try to use the "Select" it shows this error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: first_name of: 
sakila.entity.Actor [select A.first_name from sakila.entity.Actor A
 ]
```

This is the query: "select A.first_name from Actor A"

I have used other querys like "from Actor" or "from Actor where first_name=''" and they work fine, the problem just appears when i use the clause "Select".

I´m using Hibernate in Netbeans.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object sakila.entity.Actor needs to have a first_name field.

I'd also point out that by convention, Java object field names use camelCase and not snake_case.  The field should be named firstName and not first_name.  One benefit of this will be to make database columns look distinct from Java fields.  E.g. first_name is a column in a database table but firstName is a field on a Java object.

Comment: Yes, it was the problem. I´ve seen the corrects name in the hbm.xml file.  Thank you!